# Problem with Python, kivy application on smartphone

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I've written a simple application in python and kivymd, which does work on PC but doesn't work on smartphones. To convert code to apk file I used buildozer in google colab. Buildozer specfile, as well as code, looks good to me, so it should work on a mobile phone. I tried to check logcat via ADB but I don't know what to look for there are many pieces of information from my app, debug information, and warnings but I don't know which of them are important and which are just normal.

```
File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Calculator/kivymd/uix/behaviors/elevation.py", line 364, in <module>
26860  7420 I python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
26860  7420 I python: Python for android ended.
647    647  I io_stats: !@   8,0 r 50398943 1331874748 w 21301992 207147416 d 6584221 396580196 f 0 0 iot 34055544 0 th 0 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 488813.237
1348   1578 W InputDispatcher: channel '84af54b org.honi.calculator/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9, fd=1119
1348   1578 E InputDispatcher: channel '84af54b org.honi.calculator/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
1348   4563 D InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=1114
1348   1831 I ActivityManager: Process org.honi.calculator (pid 26860) has died: fg  TOP (186,1799)
943    991  I SurfaceFlinger: id=110000 Removed Bounds for - org.honi.calculator/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity@0#0 (161)
943    991  I SurfaceFlinger: id=110001 Removed SurfaceView - org.honi.calculator/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity@d69d998@0#0 (161)
943    990  I SurfaceFlinger: id=110002 Removed Background for -SurfaceView - org.honi.calculator/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity@d69d998@0#0 (161)
834    834  I Zygote  : Process 26860 exited cleanly (255)
853    853  I Sensors : batch(0) - accelerometer_sensor try to batching with 100000000
1348   2293 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{84af54b u0 org.honi.calculator/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
1348   2293 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '84af54b org.honi.calculator/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)'
```

I think that the problem must be shown in this part of logcat.
Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should look **only starts with python**

Like this:

```
26860  7420 I python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
26860  7420 I python: Python for android ended.
```

Because they are logs from **Kivy Application.**

But anyway you should **check** the buildozer.spec file for log level.